# Распарсить conf файл с одинаковыми именами секций

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

подскажите, каким образом можно распарсить файл *.conf, который содержит одинаковые секции, например:

```
[section]
name = value
test1 = 1
test2 = 3
test3 = 4

[section]
name = value2
test1 = 11
test2 = 33
test3 = 44

[section]
name = value3
test1 = 111
test2 = 333
test3 = 444
```

Стандартные библиотеки(configparser, configObj) ругаются на дубликаты секций. В случае, в configparser передавать параметр strict = False, то возвращается лишь последняя секция, тогда как  их там огромное количесвто.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121171/discussion-on-question-by-alexander--conf-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ручной парсинг с проходом по файлу построчно (считаем, что у всех секций имя `[section]`):

```
sections = []

with open("sections.conf") as file:
    current_object = None
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() == "[section]":
            if current_object is not None:
                sections.append(current_object)
            current_object = dict()
        elif current_object is not None:
            key, sep, value = map(str.strip, line.partition("="))
            if not sep:
                print("Отустствует = в строке", line)
                continue
            current_object[key] = value
    
    if current_object:
        sections.append(current_object)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(sections)
```

Для примера файла из вопроса будет такой результат:

```
[{'name': 'value', 'test1': '1', 'test2': '3', 'test3': '4'},
 {'name': 'value2', 'test1': '11', 'test2': '33', 'test3': '44'},
 {'name': 'value3', 'test1': '111', 'test2': '333', 'test3': '444'}]
```

Comment: Отлично!Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот в порядке эксперимента можно попробовать `pandas`:

```
mport pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("cfg.cfg", header=None)

df["grp"]=df[0].str.contains(r"\[").astype("int").cumsum()
grp = [g[0][1:].tolist() for i, g in df.groupby('grp')]
```

в `grp` у вас теперь список списков. Например, `grp[0]`:

```
['name = value', 'test = 1', 'test = 3', 'test = 4']
```